# How to create a Film Emulsion Border using Photoshop CS?

Tags: software, photoshop

The latest version of Adobe Photoshop Express for the iPhone allows you to add a border called Film Emulsion to your photos.

It seems like this should be something that can be easily done in the full version of Photoshop CSx, but the only way I can figure out how to do it is very manual and long for such a simple effect.

Any ideas on how to do this quickly?

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of plugins and add-on scripts that do this. For example:

- http://sloppy.jamescookphotography.com/
- http://www.redgiantsoftware.com/products/all/vintage-film/
- http://www.autofx.com/products/ds2/effects/filmFrameArt.html
- http://www.liknes.no/photoshop/bordergallery.htm

Some of these are free, some are priced highly enough to make me make kind of a funny face. But you can also take the long manual process and [roll it up into your own action](http://blog.epicedits.com/2008/03/07/how-to-create-photoshop-actions/).